# Align the navbar correct between logo and basket

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having some trouble with my navbar on this [site](https://mimsi.dk/). The navbar is going below where it should be. As I see it there is 2 problems.

**1:** There is to much width between the menu. When I remove a menu option, the menu is aligning fine.

**2**
I had to set this CSS on the following line of HTML, because the logo was not clickable. If I remove the inline-block the menu is aligning perfect, but then the logo is not clickable.

`<nav id="wp-megamenu-primary_navigation" class="wp-megamenu-wrap">`

```
#wp-megamenu-primary_navigation {   
    padding-right: 15px !important;
    padding-left: 15px !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I need to make the menubar align between the logo and checkout basket, and still make the logo and basket clickable.

Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with setting the padding 1px (from 14 to 13px )lower on this class:

```
.wp-megamenu-wrap .wpmm-nav-wrap > ul > li > a {
    padding: 15px 13px;
}
```